# MATLAB - How to load and handle of a big TXT file (32GB)

Tags: matlab, file, memory, import, bigdata

First os all, sorry about my english...

I would like to know a better way to load and handle a big TXT file (around 32GB, matrix 83.000.000x66). I already tried some experiments with TEXTSCAN, IMPORT (out of memory), fgets, fget1,.... Except import approach, all methods works but take to much time (much more than 1 week).

I aim to use this database to execute my sampling process and, after that, a neural network for learning the behabiour.

Someone know how to import this type of data faster? I am thinking to make a database dump in other format (instead TXT), for exemplo SQL server and try to handle with this data accessing the database by queries.

Other doubt, after load all data, can I save in .MAT format and handle with this format in my experiments? Other better idea?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's impossible to hold such big matrix (5,478,000,000 values) in your workspace/memory (unless you've got tons of ram). So the file format (.mat or .csv) doesn't matter!
You definitly have to use a database (or split the file in sevaral smaller ones and calculate step by step (takes very long too).

Personaly, I only have experiances with sqlite3 and did similar with a 1.47mio x 23 matrix/csv file.
http://git.osuv.de/markus/sqlite-demo (Remember that my `csv2sqlite.m` was just designed to run with GNU Octave [19k seconds at night ...well, it was bad scripted too :) ].
After everything was imported to the sqlite3 database, I simply can access only the data I need within 8-12 seconds (take a look in the comment header of `leistung.m`).

If your csv file is straight, you can simply import it with sqlite3 itself
For example:

```
┌─[markus@x121e]─[/tmp]
└──╼ cat file.csv 
0.9736834199195674,0.7239387515366997,0.3382008456696883
0.6963824911102146,0.8328410999877027,0.5863203843393815
0.2291736458336333,0.1427739134201017,0.8062332551565472
┌─[markus@x121e]─[/tmp]
└──╼ sqlite3 csv.db
SQLite version 3.8.4.3 2014-04-03 16:53:12
Enter ".help" for usage hints.
sqlite> CREATE TABLE csvtest (col1 TEXT NOT NULL, col2 TEXT NOT NULL, col3 TEXT NOT NULL);
sqlite> .separator ","
sqlite> .import file.csv csvtest
sqlite> select * from csvtest;
0.9736834199195674,0.7239387515366997,0.3382008456696883
0.6963824911102146,0.8328410999877027,0.5863203843393815
0.2291736458336333,0.1427739134201017,0.8062332551565472
sqlite> select col1 from csvtest;
0.9736834199195674
0.6963824911102146
0.2291736458336333
```

All is done with https://github.com/markuman/go-sqlite (Matlab and Octave compatible! but I guess no one but me has ever used it!) 
However, I recommand Version 2-beta in branch 2 (`git checkout -b 2 origin/2`) running in `coop` mode (You'll hit max string length from sqlite3 in `ego` mode). There's a html doku for version 2 too. http://go-sqlite.osuv.de/doc/

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will try to deal with this directly from database access.